# Laravel Subquery: display items if subquery returns available quantity

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, closures

I am trying to get all items with its available_qty

> available_qty is based on the table transactions which has columns item_id, type(enum=['in','out']) and qty
>
> Items table is the parent table of transactions which has columns name, description, unit...,etc

all i have tried so far is this.

```
SELECT name, 
(
    (SELECT sum(qty) from transactions WHERE items.id=transactions.item_id and type='in')
        -
    (SELECT sum(qty) from transactions WHERE items.id=transactions.item_id and type='out')
) as available_qty FROM `items`;
```

the above query will return null if one of the subqueries returns null even though the other subquery returns positive number.

[image]

i want to get the actual available quantity. and i want to convert this subquery into model get method with addSelect or closure.. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just Join the two tables and and sum the `qty` based on the `type` value

```sql
SELECT i.name, SUM(CASE WHEN t.type='in' THEN t.qty ELSE (t.qty * -1) END) AS available_qty
FROM items i, transactions t
WHERE i.id = t.item_id
GROUP BY i.name
HAVING available_qty > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks So much... it works. I am not very familiar with that advance query. I will learn more about this stuff in my free time.

Comment: i want to only display the available qty which has greater than zero. i tried 
where SUM(CASE WHEN t.type='in' THEN t.qty ELSE (t.qty * -1) END) > 0 but its no luck

Comment: You an use `Having` in this case, updated the answer

Comment: Thank you so much. there's really a lot to learn for me..